How do I find out what is causing Edge Developer Tools to be BLANK on the company ASP.NET WebForms website?
We have an old ASP.NET WebForms site that currently only runs in Microsoft Edge because of the way hundreds of links open in popup windows. It needs to be rewritten, but that is our long-term project that has not been approved resources yet.
I recently learned how to use a timer to update Page 1 when dialog on Page 2 calls a 3rd dialog on Page 3. Page 3 sets a Session variable, and Page 1 listens for it.
This is my Page 1:
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var csrWhere = '<%=Session("csrWhere")%>'
                if (csrWhere != '') {
                    alert(csrWhere);
                    location.reload();
                }
            }, 200);
        });
    </script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadMenu ID="mnuMain" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" CssClass="RadMenu_Claim" EnableShadows="true" OnClientItemClicking="MenuOpenWindow" CollapseAnimation-Type="None" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Style="z-index: 999; position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 12px" runat="server" />
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="XmlSiteMapProviderHome" runat="server" />

It is not firing, so I tried to pull up the Developer Tools and query some information using the Javascript console. That was when I noticed that Developer Tools will open, but the content of the page is blank:

By contrast, I can come here on the same PC running the same browser, and Developer Tools works like it should.

Obviously, something on the site is interfering with Developer Tools. We have 2 developers at our company, and neither of us have ever seen this or know what is causing it.
This website project has numerous older third party DLLs like Telerik and an older Javascript library, and I suspect it is one of those.
Does anyone know how I would find out what is blocking my Developer Tools?
Update
In the Web.config file, I found this:
<authorization>
    <allow roles="VistaUser" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>

Is it possible that the Visual Studio Debugger role needs access? I'd like to test that theory, but I do not know what that role is called at this moment. I'm going to see if I can find that.

Same issue reported here: https://superuser.com/questions/1193858/microsoft-edge-developer-tools-window-stays-blank, try if any of the answers works for you.


Obviously, something on the site is interfering with Developer Tools.

Actually not. Have you noticed the little IE icon in the left of your address bar:

It means you are running this page in Internet Explorer mode. The Chromium DevTools apparently won't work in IE mode.
To debug the content of an IE mode tab, use IEChooser to open Internet Explorer DevTools, as follows:

In Windows, open the Run dialog. For example, press Windows logo key + R.

Enter %systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe, and then click OK.

In IEChooser, select the entry for the IE mode tab.


Of course, you may wonder why you're in IE mode. Normally, it is configured by your company (using group policies and such) for legacy application compatibility. In case you don't want to run this application in IE mode, you can contact your administrator for more information.

That looks like my issue. I launched Edge using the Powershell command start msedge --remote-debugging-port=60629, but it only brought up the blank Edge page. While debugging my app, I copied the URL and pasted it into the Edge window, but it immediately changed to display the IE compatibility mode logo that you noticed.

@jp2code Sounds like this URL is configured by your company to open in IE mode every time. You may not be able to change it, so simply try IEChooser if you need to debug this page.

As a general rule, when using a update panel, you have to open the developer tools (f12) in the browser BEFORE the page loads!
If not, and you jump to some page, then open developer tools, and hit refresh on the browser, and THEN click on buttons etc.


I recently learned how to use a timer to update Page 1 when dialog on Page 2 calls a 3rd dialog on Page 3. Page 3 sets a Session variable, and Page 1 listens for it.


Apparently not!
Really, I don't suggest such a hack design be attempted at all. What happens if the user opens up more then one tab? Really, but really really, this is not going to produce a stable nor robust enviorment.
Since popup blockers are LONG gone from the web land, then I suggest you simply replace the popups with a NICE popup utility. I at one time used the AjaxToolKit dialog, but far better is to build a REALLY nice dialog control (ascx). That way, for any page, you can simple drag + drop in this dialog control, and you are off to the races.
As for what (of many choices) dialog popup to use? Well, there is the bootstrap ones, but they are kind of jinkey in terms of how they are launched. Best choice is thus to adopt the jQuery.UI one, and it REALLY works nice.
How do these dialog utilities get past the popup blocker? Why of course they "fake" the popup, and use a div that is created, and with css, they look like a popup, behave like a popup, but are standard HTML markup, and thus no popup block will care, touch, or prevent as such, since then the browser would have to stop working and stop allowing standard HTML markup to work!!
So, say we have say some delete button, (server side code), and we want to popup a prompt to confirm the button click. So, if user hits no, then we do nothing, but if user hits yes, then we want the given button code to run.
So, say this markup:
        <asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"
            OnClientClick="return mydelete(this);"
            OnClick="cmdDelete_Click"
            CssClass="btn myshadow"
            />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        <div id="mypopdiv" style="display:none">
            <h3>Delete this record</h3>
            <h4><i>(this can't be undone)</i></h4>
        </div>


    <script>
        var mydeleteok = false
        function mydelete(btn) {

            if (mydeleteok) {
                mydeleteok = false
                return true
            }
            myDialog = $("#mypopdiv")
            myDialog.dialog({
                title: "Delete ?",
                modal: true,
                sizable: true,
                width: '300',
                appendTo: "form",
                closeText: "",
                dialogClass: "dialogWithDropShadow",
                position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
                buttons: [
                    {
                        id: "mydel",
                        text: "Delete",
                        class: "btn myshadow",
                        click: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                            mydeleteok = true
                            $(btn).click()
                            return
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        id: "Cancel",
                        text: "Cancel",
                        class: "btn myshadow",
                        click: function () {
                            myDialog.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
            return false
        }
    </script>

And code behind is thus this:
Protected Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    lblMsg.Text = "Server code delete will run"


End Sub

Hence, the result is if user hits "delete", then code behind runs. If user hits cancel, then the server side code does not run.

So, the above gives a nice dialog, and also gives a nice (easy) way to conditional run a button click.
And the above jQuery.UI dialog also works well for display of any "div" content.
So say for editing, then we can use the dialog like this:

So, in place of attempting to use some loop with session() (which is going to be difficult at best), I suggest you replace the window() pops with a jQuery.UI dialog control. Obviously you want to build a nice re-useable library for this purpose, and have some kind of "my pop" routine that you can call with some parameters. Either way, adopting some kind of dialog system for your code will not only allow far easier refactoring by replacing the window() popup with a call to some JavaScript library, but you dialog code can follow a rather "similar" design pattern to what you have now. This would be far better then attempting to poll some other page via session().

That is a great idea, and it has been on our task list for a few years. But, we have been told that we have to change them all if we change one, and we do not have the resources (man power) to accomplish that at this time.

Attempting some polling with session() going to be more jinky and far more work then suggested right? You can't really support only running a older version of IIE browser, and you can't assume ANY modern browser will allow popups (they all block them by default). So how is some polling loop + session() is going to be less work then the above suggestion then? Replacing the window.open() with some say a call to a common JavaScript routine that pops a jQuery.UI dialog seems far less work no matter how you spin this. I mean, either you support newer browsers, or you don't.

Even if you only have resources to fix or replace a few of the requirements, either way, adopting a dialog popup is less work and less messy then any kind of polling + session() that I can think of. As noted, any browser by default will block popups, so I don't see much of a choice you have here anyway.  If you want only to fix and have a few dialogs, the existing ones will NEVER work due to popup blockers being standard in our industry.  So, in place of polling + session() I would think hands down changing the  open window to such dialogs will be less work then what you are attempting anyway.

Each of the pages is an ASP.NET WebForm that is launched with height and width parameters to var vVar = window.showModalDialog(link, window, feature); with a switch statement based on the vVar return type (i.e. __doPostBack(), CloseDialogSessionExpired(window, 2)). I don't know JavaScript that well, but I'll get there.

the jQuery.UI dialog is able to open other pages. In some cases, you have to place the page in a iframe, but you can still pop other pages with the jQuery.UI dialog. Once again, given this "use case", I can't imagine that introduction of some polling code + introduction of session() is going to be less work, nor work that well  anyway. If the issue is the amount of work, then taking a road of less resistance makes all the more sense here.

I'm just an employee, Albert. I can't approve that change. I am limited on what I can do. Management already knows the end of life is coming for IE Mode.

No worries, all so often developers think everyone has to live in a perfect world, and everything is all pots of gold - we are often dealt a deck of cards, and 99% of the time, it is based on history - not that anyone did anything wrong. My only suggesting here is to consider adopting some kind of dialog library code, and that will allow you to modify and continue to use the software system you have to deal with. Good luck!
